# How to show $\sin(-iy)=i\sinh(y)$?

Tags: complex-numbers

How to show $\sin(-iy)=i \sinh(y)$?

I get: $\sin(-iy)=\frac{1}{2i}(e^{-iy}-e^{iy})=\frac{1}{2i}(\cos(y)-i\sin(y)-\cos(y)-i\sin(y))=...=-\sin(y)$.

I don't get it.
$-sin(y) \neq i sinh(y)$ - [look at here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+-sin%28y%29+same+as+I%2asinh%28y%29)

Comment: use Euler's identity $ sin(x)= \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i} $ and the definition of the hyperbolic sine $ sin(x)= \frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2} $ now just compare :) since $ i(-i)=1 $

Comment: You have the identity incorrect: it's $\sin(iy)=i\sinh y$. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Sine_with_a_complex_argument)

Comment: @JoseGarcia please use `\sin` instead of `sin`. The latter looks like the product of $s$, $i$ and $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the $i$'s already in $\sin$; $\sin x = \frac{1}{2i}(e^{ix} - e^{-ix})$. So:

$$
\sin(iy) = \frac{1}{2i}(e^{i^2y} - e^{-i^2y}) = \frac{-i}{2}(e^{-y} - e^{y}) = i\sinh(y)
$$

Answer (score 3):

$$ \sin(x) = \frac{e^{i x} - e^{-i x}}{2 i}$$, then 
$$ \sin(i x) = \frac{e^{i^2 x} - e^{-i^2 x}}{2 i}= \frac{e^{-x} - e^{ x}}{2 i}$$

Comment: Three upvotes for a wrong formula for $\sin(x)$.

Comment: Perhaps instead of complaining about the upvotes to a wrong answer let us try to help the answerer to check his answer: @ox2207, your first formula is wrong: it must be $$\sin x:=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$ Of course, *also* the second formula is wrong...

Comment: You both are right. However, it doesn't matter, because topic-starter's complication was in argument substitution, not in formulas, which he/she can easily look at wikipedia or somewhere else.

Comment: @DonAntonio Perhaps you could calm down, don't you think?

Comment: I'm pretty cool and calm down the last  few weeks, @Did. Why? Do you see anything out of order somewhere?

Comment: `However, it doesn't matter`... I disagree.